# Native Mac webapp wrapper

Tags: macos, cordova, native

So for iPhone there's PhoneGap, which is awesome and gives you access to filesystem, hardware, etc. Is there something like it for mac? I've looked at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mac, but it doesn't have a lot of the stuff I need to truly make it feel native like menu bar access, filesystem access, etc. Is there something like this? Bonus points if it runs on Windows, but isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try Appcelerator Titanium ? http://www.appcelerator.com/

Answer (score 0):

The PhoneGap/Mac links is bad in the answerers question, and I personally do not want to use a piece of software named "Appcelerator Titanium". It seems that the OSX wrapper torch has been passed to

[Apache Cordova for OSX](https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx).

However, it looks like the documentation is pretty poor for the entire cordova project, so I don't have high hopes that it will be usable. I'll try to post my experiences as I have them.